# Ubuntu freezing after boot

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, wubi, freeze, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)
>   [12.04 stuck at the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126193/12-04-stuck-at-the-login-screen)

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual booting with windows 7 on my laptop without any problems and felt like doing the same on my desktop. However now that I have installed Ubuntu on the desktop through Wubi, if I boot into ubuntu the log in screen is as far as I get. I see my username and the password box but everything is completely unresponsive. I can move the mouse around the screen fine I just can't click on anything and the keyboard doesn't seem to work at all as I've tried a few shortcuts and there's no response at all. I have done a some searches and I think it's a driver issue but I don't know how to fix them as I'm pretty new to ubuntu and cannot log in at all.

Desktop specs if needed: Intel core i7 2700k, NVidia GTX 580, 8GB RAM.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sir I do not know much about Ubuntu and I want to suggest that try to install different graphic managers like lightgm or gdm. Ff it works then it will be fine.
My ubuntu was stuck on the login screen, so I install them and by opening the virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I have got the Ubuntu in the working position.