# "GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon" while installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, gpu

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 580 graphics card and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using the `nomodeset` option. Now when I start the PC, in the login screen I can't move my mouse and then a black screen appears and the following message is repeated:

```
GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon
Failed to idle channel 1
PIPFO playlist Update failed
```

I know I have to install the NVIDIA drivers, but how can I access the terminal?

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but it didn't work.

Comment: Related: [How to solve "GPU Lockup - switching to software fbcon" on new install of 12.10-desktop-amd64](https://askubuntu.com/q/205021/955434)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem forcing the GRUB to appear by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> repeatedly while starting the PC. Then I introduced `nomodeset` again and I followed [this steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126193/12-04-stuck-at-the-login-screen).

Answer (score 0):

In the GRUB screen select your Ubuntu installation and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> , find the line that begins with the word Linux and move to the end of this line , there should be something like : "**quiet splash**" , add the **nomodeset** in the brackets, press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to return to the previous menu and boot your system.

To make it permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add the **nomodeset** again press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> το exit. Then give `sudo update-grub`